# SQL Server Reporting Service 2014 installation Fail?

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssrs, installation

I have an issue while trying to install SQL Server 2014 (Reporting Service only).

During the Installation process i get the following error and the installation ends with Failed to install the followings:

Reporting Service - Native

Error:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Setup

The following error has occurred:

Error writing to file: Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo.dll.   Verify that you have access to that directory.

Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

---

I have Administrative  privilege on the server with full control of all folders\paths.

Please if you have an answer for this ,share it with me !

Thanks
Osama Waly

Comment: Did you launch the installation as administrator - `run as admin` ?

Comment: Run process explorer and see if there are any open handles on that filename.

Comment: Look in this directory: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log     There should be a subdirectory for every installation attempt. In that subdirectory, review the log files for a more detailed error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there was problem with the downloaded media. Tried another source and it worked fine.

Thanks

Comment: Could you mark this answer as the solution? Helps keep the SSRS tag nice and tidy. It's ok to mark your own answer as the solution.